# How does comparator in a set works with functor in C++?

Tags: c++, set, functor

Here is a simple program to show my point:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
class comparator
{
public:
  bool operator()(int* a, int* b){return *a < *b;}
};
int main()
{
  std::set<int*> v1{new int{1}, new int{1}, new int{2}, new int{2}};
  std::set<int*, comparator> v2{new int{1}, new int{1}, new int{2}, new int{2}};
  std::cout << v1.size() << std::endl; // 4
  std::cout << v2.size() << std::endl; // 2
  return 0;
}
```

Before using functor, the set removes duplicate elements by address of integers. However, after including functor, it removes based on the values. The problem is that in the functor I didn't define the operator to return `true` on duplicate values, so why would it show this behavior?

Comment: I know it's just an example, but this leaks all over the place.

Comment: Can certainly use smart pointers if it matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't define the operator to return true on duplicate values, so why would it show this behavior?

Because a `std::set` is intended to work with "less than" comparator, and it is implemented that way. That is, if for two values `x` and `y` in the set both `x<y` and `y<x` are false, then `x` and `y` are assumed to be equal and thus they are duplicates.